# Cannot process response from jQuery.post()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code

```
$(function() {
    $('.apply').click(function(e) {
        var z = $(this).attr('z-id');
        var r = $(this).attr('r-id');
        $.post(
            "/r-set-z",
            "z_id=" + z + "&r_id=" + r,
            function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

It works correct except that i see no alert with response data. Everything on server goes well. All data processing there done every time I click corresponding button. The data returning by the server is of type `application/javascript` and consist of the following

```
{"msg": "save successful"}
```

Why there is no alert after clicking a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try returning the response from the server as `application/json` and either specify JSON in your `$.post`:

```
    $.post(
        "/r-set-z",
        "z_id=" + z + "&r_id=" + r,
        function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    , 'json');
```

Or use `$.getJSON`

```
    $.getJSON(
        "/r-set-z",
        "z_id=" + z + "&r_id=" + r,
        function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    );
```

Comment: Setting content type to `application/json` solves the problem. Looks like jquery magic cannot guess `json` on `application/javascript` content type. I remember that it was able to do so several versions ago…

Answer (score 0):

try the below one.

```
alert(data.msg);
```

Also make sure that the callback is at right place